# Vue built a product to upload

Tags: vue.js, web-applications

I have problems to make my webpage build in Vue works on the server. I've build the product using `vue-build prod`. I constructed the page using `vue init bootstrap-vue/webpack my-project`.

Now just the footer is visible. I've upload the content of the dist folder. The page is: http://thegraph.es/dist/

The code is here: https://github.com/MGijon/Citython/tree/master/web

Answer (score 0):

Because all your files are pointing to the root directory.
Set your base url or move all files from your `dist` folder to your root directory.

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: './',
  //...
}
```

Comment: dist is the name of the folder inside the server where the files are, it has the same name that the folder created by build. I can't find the file vue.config.js

Comment: Create it. The Vue cli will recognize it.

Comment: I've try to add this file to the the config folder first and later to the build folder, all before build it. It' doesn't work. Where must I include it?

Comment: Read the docs. You have to create it in your root directory. Vue will detect and include it automatically. http://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config

Comment: I've read the docs and tried this and doesn't work, but thanks

Comment: Hmm ok ... Another solution may be the `<base>` tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)